# POBox address capture

Tags: regex

```
/^\s*((p(ost)?.?\s*(o(ff(ice)?)?)?.?\s+(b(in|ox))?)|b(in|ox))/i
```

Is the above the best regex to capture Post Office Box addresses?

Using the above, it failed on the ones marked below:

```
P.O. Box 123
PO 123
Post Office Box 123
P.O 123
Box 123
#123       // This one
123        // This one
POB 123
P.O.B 123  // This one
P.O.B. 123 // This one
Post 123
Post Box 123
```

Any more you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegexLib.com has a pretty good [list of a number of different expressions](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=po%20box) you can use.

Comment: They only have 2 to capture PO Boxes and neither catch all of the above.

Comment: There are only 2 in the address category. I didn't look at your search results, first.